# How to use line that read from file in grep command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm sorry for my poor English, first.
I want to read a file (tel.txt) that contains many tel numbers (a number per line) and use that line to grep command to search about the specific number in the source file (another file)!

I wrote this code :

```
dir="/home/mujan/Desktop/data/ADSL_CDR_Text_Parts_A"
file="$dir/tel.txt"
datafile="$dir/ADSL_CDR_Like_Tct4_From_960501_to_97501_Part0.txt"

while IFS= read -r line
do
    current="$line"
    echo `grep -F $current "$datafile" >> output.txt`
done < $file
```

the tel file sample :

```
44001547
44001478
55421487
```

but that code returns nothing!
when I declare 'current' variable with literals it works correctly! 
what happened?!

Comment: cat file.txt | grep <number>

Comment: Make sure you quote `"$current"`

Comment: It is also quite possible that your input file contains DOS carriage returns. If so, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings

Comment: Paste into https://www.shellcheck.net/ for line by line advice.
Then use tripleee's solution. All you need is `grep` (and maybe love. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `grep` command is redirected to write its output to a file, so you don't see it on the terminal.

Anyway, you should probably be using the much simpler and faster

```
grep -Ff "$file" "$datafile"
```

Add `| tee -a output.txt` if you want to save the output to a file and see it at the same time.

`` echo `command` `` is a buggy and inefficient way to write `command`.  (`` echo "`command`" `` would merely be inefficient.)  There is no reason to capture standard output into a string just so that you can `echo` that string to standard output.

Comment: Might also want to use grep's `-x` option (if it's available) to make these "full-line" expressions.

Comment: @ghoti Good addition, though it's not clear from the question whether the OP simply forgot to mention this, or if they need something else.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you search for the **line** var directly? I've done some tests, this script works on my linux (CentOS 7.x) with bash shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/mujan/Desktop/data/ADSL_CDR_Text_Parts_A/tel.txt"

while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo `grep "$line" /home/mujan/Desktop/data/ADSL_CDR_Text_Parts_A/ADSL_CDR_Like_Tct4_From_960501_to_97501_Part0.tx >> output.txt`
done < $file
```

Give it a try... It shows nothing on the screen since you're redirecting the output to the file output.txt so the matching results are saved there.

Comment: This preserves many of the antipatterns and inefficiencies in the original code. The [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ercho) is particularly sad.

Comment: I know, thank you for pointing it out. I was trying to keep the script in the initial form... But I'll agree, your approach is better

Answer (score 0):

You should use file descriptors when reading with while loop.instead use for loop to avoid false re-directions

```
dir="/home/mujan/Desktop/data/ADSL_CDR_Text_Parts_A"
file="$dir/tel.txt"
datafile="$dir/ADSL_CDR_Like_Tct4_From_960501_to_97501_Part0.txt"

for line in `cat $file`
do
    current="$line"
    echo `grep -F $current "$datafile" >> output.txt`
done
```